# how to upload a folder includes sub folders?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is there anyway that I can use asp.net [webforms] to allow users to upload entire directory that has files and **sub directories** ?
I've seen many examples that use **webkitdirectory** .. but at the bet of my knowledge, it only works with Google Chrome  .. also it won't work upload the sub directories ( it uploads all the files together in one directory ?

most of the similar questions were old .. and use FileUpload control for a single file .. nothing at all worked to upload folder that has sub folders!

I know that I can zip in the client side and unzip the folder in the server ( that would be my last option ) .. but my question about the possibility of uploading the directory? 
any solution for that?

Comment: What about zipping the entire structure and upload a single smaller file? A separate thread on the server could restore the structure "as is"

Comment: thanks @Steve for your reply .. that's actually my last option that I'm thinking of .. but I'm trying to find a way that I can allow users to upload the folder directly without asking them to zip the folder  .. I just want to make sure that there is no way to do it as requested to convince my supervisour. so is there a way to do it ? many thanks..